# Change CAShapeLayer path with stimulate animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

I am trying to make an animation like this:

[image: Graph animation]

I tried it by changing the CA Shape layer path animation using `CABasic` animation, its working, But  can't able to achieve the stimulation. I tried of using CA Keyframe animation, still I can't. If any one have ideas share.

Comment: Can you share some code for what you've tried and what you think isn't working with it?

Comment: @SandyChapman here is the code '  CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
                            [pathAnimation setDelegate:self];
                            pathAnimation.duration = 0.8;
                            pathAnimation.fromValue = (__bridge id)oldPath;
                            pathAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)newPath;
                            [pathAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.5 :1.4 :1 :1]];
                            [pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"path"];
'

Comment: Using this method am changing every path based on change in points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the animation. I'm afraid you need to change the path of your line one by one.

1. The path is all 0 on y-axis.
2. The first animation animate the path from all-0s to path with only all-0s except the first node.
3. After some time(using CATiming protocol to specific the time), animate the path from the destination in 2 to a path with all-0s except the frist 2 nodes.
4. Repeat the 3 till the all nodes are animated.

You can group all the animations of path with CAAnimationGroup.

Comment: Yeah you are brilliant. But i had already tried this. Group animation alone i need to check. But for that too i need to create separate path for each and every nodes. so it won't be good. So i need to make it using some other method.

Comment: I think it's unavoidable, such kind of animation deserve the complexity of code. If you have better idea, please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey friend, I did it by the same way with some tricky idea , i mean by changing the path one by one with stimulate animation.